# How to show $\sum{(-1)^n \frac{e^{-nx}}{n}}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^n \frac{e^{-nx}}{n}}$ 
  converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

The notes I have say: for any fixed $x$ the series converges by the Liebniz test. But recalling the tail end in the Liebniz test, we get that the tail end of the series is estimated as, $|r_n(x)| \leq \frac{e^{-(n+1)x}}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$ so the series converges uniformly on the given interval.

I know that if the sequence of partial sums $s_n(x) = f_1(x) + ... + f_n(x)$ converges uniformly, then so to does the series. However I am not sure how they estimated the tail end of the series here.

Comment: Have you considered looking at pairs of terms (which are strictly positive/negative) and computing the maximum so as to use the Weierstrass M-test? I

Comment: I know there are other methods of doing it, but I would like to know how the tail end of this series was worked out

Answer (score 0):

The tail is an alternating series whose terms are decreasing in absolute value. The sum is then bounded by the first term.

Comment: But isn't the first term given by $-e^{-x}$?

Comment: Apply it to the tail series.

Comment: I still don't see how we get what was in the notes (which I wrote in the question)

Comment: The first term of the tail series $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty{(-1)^n \frac{e^{-nx}}{n}}$ is $(-1)^{n+1} \frac{e^{-(n+1)x}}{n+1}$.

Comment: In my question above, the minus sign is left out, is that because $a \leq |a|$?

Comment: It is a bound on the absolute value of the tail series.